# Proof Verification: $ (ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am asked to prove $$(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$.

Here is what I have:

$$(ab)^{-1} = \frac{1}{ab} = \frac{1}{a} * \frac{1}{b} =a^{-1}b^{-1}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Where are $a$ and $b$ from?

Comment: Oops!  Forgot to add.  They belong to R.  I will update that now.

Comment: By the way, you can type `$\Bbb{R}$` to get the $\Bbb{R}$ symbol.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the proof. The middle line $\frac{1}{ab} = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{b}$ is precisely the thing you need to prove.

Comment: Tip, when using mathjax with exponents larger than one character write them with brackets like `a^{bc}`.

Comment: Try starting with the equation $(ab)(ab)^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: Obviously you can have noncommutative multiplication over $\mathbb{R}$, but perhaps this is just assumed.  In general, we actually do not have this; rather, $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, so it would help to know a few more specifics.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  The way I came up with this is that the texts defines the binary operation / on $\Bbb{R}$$-{{0}}$ as $a/b=ab^{-1}$.  Is that enough to assume the "/"?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you...  What do you mean, "Is that enough to assume the "/"?"?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(ab)^{-1}$ is the unique solution for $(ab)\cdot x=1$. Now, for us to show that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ what we need to do is to verify that $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})=1$. Using associativity, commutativity for multiplication and existence of multiplicative inverse and identity you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the unicity of $x^{-1}$, that is: demostrate first that for every $x\neq 0$ there exists a **unique** $x^{-1}$ such that $x*x^{-1} = 1$. Then, using that, prove that $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ is $(ab)^{-1}$, because $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1}) = 1$